# Template overriding worked in Magento 2.4.2 doesnt get triggered in Magento 2.4.6-p2

Tags: magento2.4.2, magento2.4.6

I have custom Magento module which was originally deployed and worked properly in Magento 2.4.2 , which injects some JS to frontend product page, with some backend connectivity. After copying same to Magento 2.4.6-p2 expected template overriding does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">            
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" template="Iwdat_StockManager287::stock_update.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

There is no error on page or in logs. According to templatehints the custom template file is not loaded.

Is there any changes in defining a template overriding in 2.4.6 ? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: Summary of the backward incompatible changes: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/backward-incompatible-changes/highlights/ all changes: https://github.com/magento/magento2/compare/2.4.2..2.4.6-p2

Comment: Thank you very much